# Is there a way to set the output location for unix zip command?

Tags: php, unix, location, zip, exec

Hi I'm trying to create a zip file by using the PHP exec method.
For example:

```
exec("/usr/bin/zip -r5 archive.zip /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/uploads/test");
```

However I haven't found the way to set the output location of the archive.zip
Is it even possible? I have read the documentation but didn't found it, or maybe it's called something else to achieve what I want !?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just add the location which you want to save in the exec? Like so: `exec("/usr/bin/zip -r5 /saved/path/to/archive.zip /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/uploads/test");`

Comment: If you are using PHP the built-in [ZipArchive class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) may be helpful instead of relying on an external system call.

Comment: @Dave I already tried that, it doesn't work because I have folders with large and many files in them. So when I try to zip with PHP my application runs out of memory even when increasing the memory. That's why I need to do this on server side.

Comment: @Efekan thanks that worked, stupid I didn't think of that :).